# To click on all check box and match [Ruby Selenium-webdriver]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

When i click on select all checkbox then right corner value shows that you "selected 4 " i need to write case to match with selected 4

How can i do that? I am using ruby selenium

```
driver.find_element(:name, "xbox").click 
element :selectedcount, :css, 'span[id=systems_removal_count]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but it looks like you're using site_prism so I'm assuming you have some sort of page object which I'll name @home on which the `selectedCount` element is defined. Mathew to check for the text you could do something like

```
expect(@home.selectedCount).to have_text('selected 4')
```

Or

```
expect(@home.selectedCount).to have_text('4')
```

Depending on exactly what you're expecting to be in that element